# Como adicionar funcionalidades a um Model que dependam do Controller ou da View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Eu gostaria de acrescentar os seguintes métodos ao meus Models quando apresentados na View, como por exemplo, `can_be_showed`, `can_be_edited`, `can_be_destroyed`, entre outros, porém em alguns casos, esses métodos podem depender do *Controller*, como por exemplo depender do usuário que está logado.

Já tentei utilizar o padrão *Presenter*, porém eu encontrei muitos problemas, como por exemplo para renderizar o *Persenter* como fosse um Model:

```
<%= render my_presenter %>#=render partial: 'my_models/my_model, locals: {my_model: @my_model}
```

Passá-lo como parâmetro para uma método de roteamento:

```
link_to 'title', edit_my_model(@my_presenter)
```

Ou criar um formulário com base nele

```
form_for(@my_presenter) do |f|
```

Alguém teria alguma dica, seguida de exemplo?, eu gostaria de algo que me desse a oportunidade de reaproveitar o máximo de código o possível.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no https://github.com/elabs/pundit

Comment: ouvi falar da Draper Decorator na conferencia do rails 2014 https://github.com/drapergem/draper , primeiro irei testar este, qualquer coisa informo o resultado aqui

Answer (score 1):

Minha solução seria criar os métodos:
`can_be_showed_by(current_user)` `can_be_edited_by(current_user)` e `can_be_destroyed_by(current_user)` e dessa forma poder usar o usuário logado e poderia aproveitar o código todo em outras rotinas, já que o current_user é só uma instância do User.